# MySQL Procedure wont let me set variable value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Im having trouble with a procedure, Im getting error 1064 where im setting a value of a declare variable.

heres the code.

```
use lab3New;
delimiter $
drop procedure if exists Q4C;
create procedure Q4C()  
BEGIN
    declare bonus decimal(8,2);
    declare count int;
    declare done int;
    declare empSL decimal(8,2);
    declare tmpSL decimal(8,2);
    declare empID int;
    
    set bonus = 100000;
    set count = 0;
    
    declare myCursor cursor for
    select salary, employee_id
    from employees
    order by salary asc;
    
    declare continue handler for not found set done = TRUE;
    open myCursor;
    read_loop:LOOP
        fetch myCursor into empSL, empID;
        if done then leave read_loop; end if;
        set tmpSL = .2 * empSL;
        if tmpSL > bonus then
            update employees
            set salary = salary + bonus
            where employee_id = empID;
            
            set bonus = 0;
            set count = count + 1;
            end loop;
        else 
            set bonus = bonus - tmpSL;
            set salary = salary + tmpSL
            where employee_id = empID;
            set count = count + 1;
        end if;
    end loop;
    close myCursor;
    
    select count;
    
END$
delimiter ;
```

and the table

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| employee_id    | decimal(6,0) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| first_name     | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| last_name      | varchar(25)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| email          | varchar(25)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| phone_INT      | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| hire_date      | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| job_id         | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| salary         | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| commission_pct | decimal(2,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| manager_id     | decimal(6,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| department_id  | decimal(4,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

this is the error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare myCursor cursor for
    select salary, employee_id
    from employees
    order b' at line 11
```

any ideas? Ive tried using default and setting the value but in my loop where I increment `count` i then get the error 1064 at that line. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `DECLARE` statements must be placed before any other statement in the code block. Whereas you put `DECLARE CURSOR` (and `DECLARE HANDLER`) after `SET` statements.

---

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  DECLARE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare.html)

> `DECLARE` is permitted only inside a `BEGIN ... END` compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.